# How does SystemVerilog handle possible wildcard conflicts in case statements?

Tags: system-verilog, case-statement

When I write a case statement that includes wildcards for the cases, how are more or less specific cases handled?

```
always_comb case(selector)
    4'b0???: begin // Pick me if the msb is 0, unless the two lsb's are 01.
    end
    4'b0?01: begin // Pick me if the msb is 0 and the two lsb's are 01.
    end
    default: begin // Pick me if the msb is X or 1.
    end
endcase
```

In the simplified example above, the first case (all wildcards) could be selected for any value of selector, but I want it to select the most specific possible case. Is that how cases are handled?

Comment: cases are always priority based and once a case statement is matched, all the statement below that case won't be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SystemVerilog assumes the case statement is in priority order - the second item is never matched. So you need to move the most specific cases first. SystemVerilog has `unique case` and `priority case` constructs to better specify your intent.

Comment: Could I use the unique modifier with my example? Would it convey the design intent that the more specific case and the less specific case are mutually exclusive (always take the more specific case if possible)? Placing the more specific case first and marking it priority would be less readable for my use.

Comment: No, `unique case` means you guaranteeing that only one case item will ever match for any value of `selector`. And a _don't care_ means you don't care bout the value of that bit position, so you will get multiple matching items. If your more specific case items have higher priority than other matching items, they need to specified first.